# ReadAsText() arguments

Tags: javascript

I'm totally new to javascript (Hello World Level), I've made a lot of searches in google but couldn't even find one result explaining what arguments the ReadAsText() method get. I've tried to put the address of a file and encoding format but I keep receiving "Type mismatch" error. I'm using it this way :

```
reader.readAsText ("d:\\file.txt", "UTF-8");
```

I know that this question is not really a match for StackOverFlow but if I found any result in google I wouldn't post it here.

By the way when I use it this way it works very well:

```
function FileReader (f) {
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsText (f);
 var text = reader.result();
}
```

and then

```
<input type="file" onchange="readfile(this.files[0])"></input>
```

but I don't know why it shows error when I type in the address of the file statically.

Comment: Here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsText%28%29. The first argument has to be a `Blob` or `File` object.

Comment: Read some documentation, it only accepts a `Blob` or `File`, not a string as a path: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsText()

Comment: I'm trying to use it on win 8 apps, so there's no browser. The Visual Studio shows a "Type Mismatch" error.

Comment: @FirstLast You provided HTML...how is that not in a browser? And what does that matter?

Comment: `ths.files` here is a [`FileList` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), so `this.files[0]` is a [`File` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), not a string.

Comment: @Ian: Win 8 apps support HTML5.

Comment: @FirstLast Didn't know that. Still my question is - what does that matter? `readAsText` doesn't change because it's not in a browser

Comment: I just meant it has nothing to do with a specific browser,

Comment: @lan: HTML is not only for browsers. It is a computer language.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand that, but when the only tag on the question is "javascript" and they provide HTML, it's kinda hard not to assume in a browser (without more of an explanation first)

Comment: @FirstLast I guess I'm wondering why you think that anything would be different between a browser's environment and a Windows 8 app, that would change the functionality of `readAsText` and allow strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsText%28%29) takes a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FBlob) or [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFile) object as the first argument; any argument of a different type will cause the type error. In your working example you pass a File object which is why it works.

Comment: What exactly is a Blob, would you please explain a little more?

Comment: @First: Follow the link.

Comment: @FirstLast I'd recommend MDN's "[Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)" article as a starting point.